# Django: "conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations" from sqlite3 to Postgres

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, django-south

I've been working on a sqlite3 database with a Django project. I'm moving the project to the production environment where I use Postgres. I've used South, so I have all my migrations automated.

I'm running into the following error while trying to migrate the schema:

```
[05/Feb/2013 16:38:31] DEBUG [south:270] execute "ALTER TABLE "frontend_userprofile" ADD COLUMN "id" serial NULL PRIMARY KEY;" with params "[]"
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "frontend_userprofile" ADD COLUMN "id" serial NULL PRIMARY KEY;
The error was: conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for column "id" of table "frontend_userprofile"

[..]

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for column "id" of table "frontend_userprofile"
```

This is the relevant part of the migration file:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Adding field 'UserProfile.id'
    db.add_column('frontend_userprofile', 'id',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(default=None, primary_key=True, null=True),
                  keep_default=False)


    # Changing field 'UserProfile.user'
    db.alter_column('frontend_userprofile', 'user_id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField')(to=orm['auth.User'], unique=True, null=True))

[..]

    'frontend.userprofile': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'UserProfile'},
        'company': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'default': 'None', 'to': "orm['frontend.Company']", 'null': 'True'}),
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'user': ('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField', [], {'to': "orm['auth.User']", 'unique': 'True', 'null': 'True'})
    }
```

And of the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user    = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, default=None)
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by Jordan, you can't have both a null primary key, so the following changes solve this problem:

```
    db.add_column('frontend_userprofile', 'id',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(default=None, primary_key=True),
                  keep_default=False)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user    = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, default=None)
```

But I still have a problem finishing the migration:

```
DEBUG [south:270] execute "ALTER TABLE "frontend_userprofile" ADD COLUMN "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;" with params "[]"
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "frontend_userprofile" ADD COLUMN "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
The error was: multiple primary keys for table "frontend_userprofile" are not allowed

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: multiple primary keys for table "frontend_userprofile" are not allowed
```

I think the reason is that in a previous migration `user_id` has been set to primary key and now it's trying to add `id` as primary key. Any help with this?

Comment: I know nothing about Python but in standard SQL a primary key column cannot be NULL.

Comment: Alvaro is right and delete also unique=True because you are already use OneToOneField which understandable in Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a NULL primary key, as far as i know. That would be bad.

I recommend removing the part that says Null=True in that migration and trying again.

Comment: thanks, that solved he problem. Can you please take a look at my edit for another problem i'm facing? thanks.

Comment: It seems these tables already exist? Your migration is out of sync with reality. Either you need to delete the column from the DB table or delete the line from your migration. Or, you can separate that line out to its own migration if it isn't already, and then update south_migrationhistory to say that it's been applied.